# Refreshing page always resolves to top level

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, passenger

I am deploying my app on an ec2 machine. There is a node app which corresponds to myapp.com/api. This is working fine. The Client app is built on React and users visit it on myapp.com. 
The client app is getting rendered and i am able to navigate to different paths. However when I refresh a page, eg. myapp.com/profile it always resolves to myapp.com.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name myapp.com;
        root /home/ec2-user/projects/synaid/client/build;
        passenger_enabled on;

        index index.html;

        location / {
          root /home/ec2-user/projects/synaid/client/build;
          try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
        location /api {
            root   /home/ec2-user/projects/synaid/server/build;
            rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
            passenger_enabled on;
            passenger_app_type node;

            passenger_app_root /home/ec2-user/projects/synaid/server/build;
            passenger_startup_file index.js;
            passenger_env_var APP_ENV staging;
        }
}
```

What I thing is happening is that when nginx server gets a request it is slicing the url from base path and rendering the index.html to browser. It should also be passing the url forward to the app, which it doesnt seem to be doing. 
A possible solution could be to forward url to the app from inside the configuration.

Comment: What the nginx server will do is send the `index.html` file for any of the requests that don't match with `/api`, thus, the React App responds as it loads inside the `index.html`, so, the problem might be in the react router itself, have you verified this behavior doesn't happen at Dev mode on your local machine?

Comment: Yes on local where it deploys without nginx React is handling routing perfectly.

Comment: Can you show your react-router config?